# Batch - Copying Files depending on their timestamp

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, backup

i have two Directories (with sub-directories), A and B. B is a old copy of A, so it's likely that there are:

1) Files in A, but not in B

2) Files in B, but not in A

3) Files in A with a newer 'last modified' Timestamp

I want to identify all of these by copying them into another Directory, C

I've tried looping over all files in A an calling another batch to compare timestamps, but i wasn't able to find the corresponding file in B.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: In other words: "B" is my Backup of "A". Now I want to create a differential Backup in "C"

Comment: Why don't you show us what code you have so far

Comment: Main.bat: `for /r %%i in (*) do call copy.bat %%i`

Comment: And Copy.bat `set _Newer=1
For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('xcopy /DHYL %1 correspondingFile.txt ^|Findstr /I "File"') Do set /a _Newer=%%I 2>Nul
if %_Newer%==1 ( )else (#insertCopyFunction)`  Problem is: How do I get a value for correspondingFile.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will use `xcopy /l` to retrieve the list of files in A that differ from B. Then each file is copied to the adecuated folder in C

The initial `pushd` will allow to use the `xcopy` command to return relative paths in the form

```
.\file.ext
.\folder\file.ext
```

The initial dot is removed by the `delims=.` and the second `for` concatenates the C folder path and the retrieved file path to determine the final target.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folderA=%cd%"
    set "folderB=c:\temp"
    set "folderC=c:\temp2"

    pushd "%folderA%"
    for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%a in ('xcopy . "%folderB%" /dehyil ^| find ".\"') do for %%b in ("%folderC%%%a") do (
        echo %%b 
        if not exist "%%~dpb" mkdir "%%~dpb" >nul 
        copy /y ".%%a" "%%~dpb" >nul
    )
    popd
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. I just had have to call it twice, with A and B swapped, to ensure, that files in B, which aren't in A, are copied to C.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use rsync ?

```
rsync -azvrc <source> <destination>
```

Comment: This would do a one-way sync of source to destination. Problem is, i want a special directory with all (and only these) files, which have changend since my last "backup".

Comment: you can have multiple source with rsync, rsync -azvrc <source1> <source2> <source3> <destination>